# Can water waves be weird shapes?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves

Can stable, non breaking water waves be shapes other than the sine wave or trochoid? Like trapeziums, triangles, asymmetrical waves, etc?

If so, how would these waves behave? Would the traditional equations for energy, speed, shoaling, etc be applicable?